# Six independent papers reporting epitaxial formation of silicene in 2012

Tags: reference-request

According to a Nature news article cited below (info-box "The rise of silicone"), six independent papers were published reporting successful epitaxial formation of silicene.
Does anyone know which those were? I am just able to find the following two papers:

- Fleurence, A., R. Friedlein, T. Ozaki, H. Kawai, Y. Wang, Y.
  Yamada-Takamura (2012). "Experimental evidence for epitaxial silicene
  on diboride thin films". Physical Review Letters 108(24)
- Vogt, P., P. De Padova, C. Quaresima, J. Avila, E. Frantzeskakis, M.C. Asensio, A. Resta, B. Ealet, G. Le Lay (2012). "Silicene: compelling experimental evidence for graphenelike two-dimensional silicon". Physical Review Letters 108(15)
- Nature (2015). "Graphene’s cousin silicene makes transistor debut". Nature news article. URL: http://www.nature.com/news/graphene-s-cousin-silicene-makes-transistor-debut-1.16839

Does anyone know where to find the other four?

Comment: Could you please expand your link into [actual citations](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/citation-style-recommendation-standardisation), I (and maybe a few more people) prefer not going through pubmed. What puzzles me more is, that nature does not cite these six papers. Could you also quote the section where they mention it and what references they use instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a Nature *News* article, usually it is a way of promoting a scientific article in one of the current *Nature* publications - that's why it can get away with stating "Six independent reports" without six citations attached.  In this case, it is citing this 2015 article:

> Tao, L. et al. Nature Nanotechnol.
>   http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/NNANO.2014.325 (2015)

There are many citations in that article from the 2010-2013 time period reporting silicene sheets and nanoribbons.  Keep in mind, the Fleurence et al. paper you mentioned might not be one of the six mentioned, because it uses a diboride substrate instead of silver.

Comment: Ahh, nice catch, I didn't notice that a debarred substrate was used. I will look through the references and see what I can find.

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Have an upvote ;)